# HTTPS request with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to trigger a request in my node.js app. My app has a route and when it runs I am trying to hit a url that is built dynamically. So all I need is to trigger a RESt API call to somethinglike:

`"https://www.domainname.com/sometext/"+ var1 +"/someothertext"`

So I tried this:

```
var options = {
    host: 'www.domainname.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/1.0/'+var1,
    method: 'GET'
};

//  trigger request 
request(options, function(err,response,body) {
.......
});
```

When I run this I get this error:
`options.uri is a required argument`

So, my goal here is to trigger the request that hits a dynamically built url. If I had a static url I could plug in the request, it would work fine.

Infact I tried to do this:

```
request("https://www.domainname.com/1.0/456", function(err,response,body) {
.......
});
```

and this works fine.

BUT I am trying to build the url (path) dynamically with var1 and that doesn't work.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a URL or an URI in the options that you pass as the first arguments to the `request` function

And the reason that `request("https://www.domainname.com/1.0/456",function(err,response,body) {` 
does not fail is because you are providing the url as the first argument

So change your `options` object to

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://www.domainname.com/sometext/'+ var1,
    port: 80,
    method: 'GET'
};
```

You can try trimming the value in `var1` like
`var1 = var1.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '')`;

That should remove the space.

Comment: the blank space is still there. I think the problem is in the + sign used int he concatenation, not necessarily in the var1 value... not sure how to fix that yet.

Comment: try `options.url = options.url.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '')` and see if it works

Comment: that worked for me. thank you. That removes the blank spaces that I used to get.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `options` argument that is taken by request isn't being given the correct formatted object.

The error you are receiving is because you need to send a `url or uri` as an option. This can be clarified here:

https://github.com/request/request

The following should do what you want:

So I tried this:

```
var options = {
    url: "https://www.domainname.com/sometext/"+ var1 +"/someothertext"
    method: 'GET'
};

//  trigger request 
request(options, function(err,response,body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't use that fork, mind. It hasn't been touched for a year. Use the actual NPM module or mikeal's repository.